# How to model this Pattern

Tags: modeling

I just want to know how to model this? I was tried but didn't find any way to make it x(.

[image]

Comment: I basically follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NhawJgrBKw to make the pattern up there. But that didn't work out.

Comment: Considering the video, do you want here to make it plane or spherical? Anyway, IMO, make it plane first, using a base modeled tile and use an array (with merge option) on it (don't use curves here)

Comment: somewhat related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/50667#50667 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56919/how-can-i-create-spherical-topology-from-a-2d-image/56924#56924

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can model only one segment of a pattern then repeat it on x and y axis with *array* modifiers.

If you need a repeating pattern on complex object try *tissue* plugin

http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue

Here is fast preview of the workflow, you just create some planes make some loop cuts move *edges* up and down

[image]

add *array* modifiers to see the pattern, add more planes, then increase *array count* and add *solidify* modifier, you can always adjust or modify your main object later...

[image]

Comment: oh my god. i keep thinking too complicated, how stupid am I. thanks you so much :D.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to reshape it into a sphere or something similar, you can use the *Deform* modifier.