# How to model a window screen

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am currently working on an architectural project and I was stopped at the window screens; I have no idea how to go about creating such a fine mesh without reaching ridiculous poly counts.

I could find no information whatsoever about the topic.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

dunno

Comment: if you use the search box on the top right of this page you might find some information on this an other topics, for example: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/50672#50672

Answer (score 4):

As long as you aren't going to be doing any really up-close shots of the windows, just use a plane with transparency. You don't even need an image. You can procedurally generate the texture. Mix an *Anisotropic BSDF* shader with a *Transparent BSDF* shader using a *Brick Texture* as the mix factor. To change the size, adjust the *Scale:* parameter.

[image]

Result:

[image]

If the renders are looking too dark/taking too long, you can add this to the node tree:

[image]

Comment: This is an even better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Glad to help. In this case, you can use an image texture that looks like a mesh and use a diffuse and transparent shader.

1. I downloaded a mesh looking texture.
2. Turned into black and white and upped the contrast.
3. On my plane, I set the image as a texture. NOTICE:I changed it to
   non-color data in the node.
4. I mixed a diffuse and transparent shader.
5. Used the color output from the image texture and connected it to the
   Factor input on the mixer. Noticed that the transparent shader is on
   top. (You might have to switch them around if the texture doesn't
   work).

It's important the little holes on your texture be black and the mesh white.

[image]

Comment: Is the photo in your image a render or a reference photo?

Comment: Just an image texture I grabbed from online.