# Hollowing Process for Text

Tags: text-object

I am new to Blender.  I see post about hollowing out a 3d text.  I have a project where I want to take a letter and hollow it out but be able to adjust the wall of the text so it is thicker.  Then be able to take the top or back off the text so I can print them separately. The text when finish would be around 20mm extruded. 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender's StackExchange! What exactly is your question/problem and what have you tried so far? Please take a look at the [How to ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and try to improve your question.

Comment: Very new to Blender. I want to learn how to work with text in blender so I can print them out in 3d.  I am looking for how to extrude just part of the text.  Also looking how to emboss areas of text.  Over all just a real good video or pdf on manipulating text in Blender. It would be helpful if you point me in that direction.  Thank You in advance The first project will be taking a letter hollowing out the letter and then I guess slicing the front and back off.  This would leave 3 different parts to printout.  Now the cats meow would be able to make them so they would snap back in place

Comment: This might give you an idea, re: hollowing out the text.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122795/how-to-make-a-growing-text-animation/123002#123002

Comment: Thanks not really what I am looking for.  The picture helps to see what I am trying to do with letters

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Very new on asking for help.  I guess I need to learn how to get more responds to my question.  After doing some research I have found a way to get the above text.  Text Profiles seems to be where it is at.  Shout out to Eric Lindley for his You-tube channel.  He has a great video on Text Profiles.  https://youtu.be/ttOmBGRStdQ