# Is there a revealing mask on blender VSE? Or other way to solve my problem

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm working with 3 image.

pic1 - background

pic2 - object

pic3 - object with transparent background

So pic1 will be under pic2 but I want to use pic3 to hide part of pic2 and show pic1.

I used Synfig Studio before. They called this as Revealing/Hiding Mask.

Comment: This sort of thing perhaps ?   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69863#69863     The cube behind the tree in the 2nd answer.  That had a background pic, (pic1) a cube object (pic2) and a mask which is shaped so it cuts the tree trunk shape out of the cube which is in fact sitting in front of the bkd image.

Comment: More on masking - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space

Comment: Nvm. I think it will work