# Transparency disappearing act

Tags: mesh, materials, objects, light

Running Blender v2.79b. Created a number of meshes. Have one mesh that sits above the others, which I want to be semi-transparent; it has an alpha of  0.07. However, I cannot see all of the other meshes through it. Any pointers to where I need to look gratefully appreciated.

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand, could you please show the scene and the nodes of your material? perhaps share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to help. --- Consider a helicopter flying above you. Looking up, you might see the helicopter wheels and the body, with the blades spinning above. Now consider looking from above, through the spinning blades. You'd expect to see the helicopter body. In my example, I was seeing the wheels, but not the body.

Answer (score 0):

There were objects on meshes added after the transparent object was added. These objects failed to appear through the transparent object.
The transparent object was on its own mesh.
Objects, added before the transparent object was added, appeared through it.

Moving the later added objects higher, in the Scene outliner, remedied the problem.
Objects were moved by creating new meshes and making them the parent of the objects added after the transparent object.
There's probably a better way to do this, but I'm just grateful to have found a solution.

Comment: What you've come up against in your project is a trait that can be used for discriminatory masking when rendering in OpenGL. As you've correctly pointed out, the solution is in the relative ages of one (transparent) object to another that's behind it... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941