# How do i render an object over a specific object among others?

Tags: rendering, objects

I would like to render the object highlighted here, *see image*
[image]
to be in front of the barrel like this, *see image*.
[image]
I read a couple of things about overlay scenes and render layers but it all seems too complicated. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: These might help first- if not just leave a comment.   -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941 -  and - 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69863#69863