# Reference Image & Masking by Selection

Tags: sculpting

I want to sculpt within the bounds of a selection of an image. Is there a way to use a reference image or a selected portion of a reference image to apply a mask to a planar mesh so that the mask corresponds to the selected portion. Or is there some other approach?
Thanks,
Gene

Comment: Could you add some screenshots or illustration of what you want to achieve? thx.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're referring to? Mask out a certain part of a background image, or using that item in the pic as a reference with which to make a mask perhaps?  Link - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941