# How to use masking to hide an object

Tags: texturing, masking

I need help creating an eyeball for my steve.
How do I go about hiding the part of the eyeball that went out of the white area?

I had a guess it's about masks, but I have no idea how to implement it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with a boolean object?

Comment: No. What does it mean?

Comment: This is getting a little dated now.  2.8xx does things differently. Blender's internal  and OpenGL renders may still work.  I've included this link in case it helps.  - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your eye cube a *Boolean* modifier. Create a second cube with a hole in it that is as big as your eye white area, make it invisible in the viewport and in render (*Properties panel > Viewport Display > Dsiplay As > Wire* and disable the camera icon in the *Outliner*), give your eye cube a *Boolean* modifier, mode > *Difference*, with the hole cube as *Object*. Now when you move your eyecube, the part that crosses the hole cube will be invisible:

[image]

Comment: That worked like magic! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: and of course parent the hole cube to the head or head bone so it follows its movement