# Setting a plane to clip and hide parts of objects

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to use a plane to hide parts of an object as they come into collision with it. For example the image below: the cone would not be showing the left side where it is "cut" and the monkey would not for the eye and ear that goes through the plane. I don't want to change any properties of the objects themselves, just a plane that functions as a "portal" on both sides if that makes sense.
[image]

Another example, only the left side monkey and right side cone would be showing here:
[image]

Comment: have you tried a Boolean modifier? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190225/how-to-use-masking-to-hide-an-object/190228#190228

Comment: Yes I've tried to apply boolean but since the plane is 2d wouldn't it only cut into a small slice into the objects?

Comment: you juste need to create a big cube that you place on the right and that you make invisible, it will act as if the plane makes things invisible while in fact it will be the cube

Comment: I understand your thinking but it must be a plane that clips, I deliberately put objects on both sides in my example

Comment: so create 2 cubes, one for each object?

Comment: I don't know what objects I'll have ahead of time during simulation and I don't want to dynamically generate a cube for each object... is there another method to create plane "portal"? I want during simulation for whatever collides into the plane to be "eaten" away.

Comment: you don't need a cube per object but a Boolean for each object and choose the left or the right cube, depending on what part of the object is supposed to be invisible. There might be other solutions, maybe someone will tell...