# How to key out an object in a video?

Tags: video, masking

I've **keyed out** the green screen in my video although I have an **object in the background** (circled in red) that I would like to 'key out' also. How do I achieve this? I want to add a background to the video without the furniture in the way.

I've looked at other similar questions here but I don't understand how the nodes work due to a mixture of it not being up to date with the current blender and also my lack of understanding.

--I'm using the Composition workspace.

[image]

Comment: Rotoscoping would certainly do it.

Make the alpha layered video of what you have so far lossless, then make a mask for each frame if the camera is moving, or perhaps adjust a single mask where necessary if it's not.  Blender is remarkably accurate for this sort of thing.

Comment: Further to the above...  As you only need to worry about one edge of the furniture - where it meets the other item, a single mask should be enough. If necessary, just move it to suit any frame by frame 'edge shimmer'.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!  :)  I don't know if you've been into masking.  This link is getting a little dated now but it should give you an idea what it's about - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941

Comment: Well I'm trying to figure this all out. Actually, with your mention of "Rotoscoping", you've helped me with another post that I had which, I feel didn't provide me with the answer I needed to solve the issue. Rotoscoping is what I need, although the issue I have is I require (hopefully) an up-to-date step-by-step video/link for-- blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193982/how-to-use-masks-on-video-so-that-some-elements-appear-in-the-foreground-and-oth             I want to add a tracker and rotoscope on an overlay to a video. Please help if you can because this has been driving me nuts. Thanks

Comment: I'm going off to dwell on this.  Your current project would be a simple matter to achieve, but like most things in Blender, can soak up time in the process.  Tell me, is the camera in the pic above moving or stationary?

Answer (score -1):

This video helped me with **rotoscoping**:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hppbUi2i74

Comment: please don't post links as answers, if the link changes or disappears, then the answer will make no sense. Try to make a summary of the main  ideas in the video so that the answer stands on its own. Use the video only as support, not as the core of an answer. To post links only use comments instead of answers.

Comment: How do I delete my answer? I applied the wrong answer as it was meant for a different post.