# making holes in shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am trying to make holes out from a pattern. It will be like a star and holes will be a word logo.

I am thinking to make the text as SVG then make a manual pattern in Blender and use Boolean Modifier.

_

Problems:

-It will be flat and the word will not follow the mesh (the second IMG).

-It will take a lot of time to make a pattern in blender.

I liked the one as image texter if it can be done in some how?!

And thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using this model to render images, for a game or for 3d printing? see this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105508/making-holes-in-an-object-using-an-image-as-a-referenc