# boolean modifier failure

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am trying to use the boolean modifier to cut holes inside the long object that is displayed in the picture. The holes need to have the shape of the 4 diamond pieces that or also displayed in the picture.
When I'm using the boolean modifier with the option difference selected, it only works properly with 2 of the 4 shapes (as seen in the picture).
To my knowledge both the parts are healthy. I already recalculated the normals and removed doubles on both the objects.
I also tried to triangulate bigger faces and subdivided the mesh of the diamond shapes but both resulted in worse outcomes.

I also included the blend file. [image]

Does anyone have a solution? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bmesh fails in some cases, try the **Carve** solver instead.

[image]
[Click on the image to enlarge.]

The documentation is very sparse about the inner workings of this option.

> **Solver**
>   Determines what set of algorithms are used to calculate the boolean operation. Carve uses the external Carve Library while BMesh uses Blender’s built-in library and should give better results.

Comment: In my experience of the Boolean modifier, BMesh does well with strictly *manifold* meshes and Carve can cut with a non-manifold mesh such as in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106016/29586 . I suspect that the object used in the example is not strictly manifold enough for the BMesh algorithm - since it’s 4 distinct volumes rather than one single volume.