# Want to model and bend an aluminium facade panel, but can't figure out how. Do I need to use geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, surface-deform

I want to model a small metal experimental panel to be used in a static render, but I can't figure out how to model it correctly, or bend it correctly.

[image: This is the shape I'm trying to model correctly, the inner shapes are intended to bend, but when I try that, i fail. (see next pic) The topology is also very bad, but im still very much a noob.]

This is the shape I'm trying to model correctly, the inner shapes are intended to bend, but when I try that, i fail. (see next pic) The topology is also very bad, but im still very much a noob.

[image: As you can see, the bends are very wonky, and not smooth at all.]

As you can see, the bends are very wonky, and not smooth at all.

Comment: create additional edge loops if it doesn't band smoothly, maybe share your file so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/